# How to get the list of all declared data variable of a class in another class including private variables

Tags: java

How can I  get the list of all declared data variable of a class in another class including private variables?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: why so many minus votes...i just asked what i needed

Comment: *"i just asked what i needed"*  You should research what you need.  If you need to ask here, show evidence of that research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using Reflection in java.
Ex-

```
public class Abc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ob = new A();

        Field[] f;
        String[] s;
        f = ob.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        System.out.println(f.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(f[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
class A {
    private int x = 10;
    String st = "hii";
}
```

Comment: Have to mention, that if OP would like to get not only the fields declared by current class, but all the fields of the super too, just make this implementatino recursive